# Barnes-Wall lattices’ contact polytopes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, lattices, polytopes

The contact polytopes of the Barnes-Wall lattices in 1, 2, 4, and 8 dimensions are all uniform polytopes. Is this true in any higher number of dimensions?